# Center text and picture

Tags: css

Have problem center two lines of text and a picture.
I have try different css setups.

I want it to look like this

```
------
pic    LINE1
       LINE2
------
```

My code look like this now

HTML

```
<a href="#" onclick="Channel(SVT1HD)"</a>
    <div class="channel">
        <div class="img"><img style="width: auto; height: 40px;" img src="img/svt1hd.png" alt="SVT1"></div>
        <div id ="channel1_title" class="title">Aktuellt Program</div>
        <div id ="channel1_info" class="info">Info</div>
    </div>
</a>
```

CSS

```
body {
    margin: 20px;
    background: #595757;
}

.channel {
    background: #393737;
}

.title {
    vertical-align:top;
    font: bold 20px/1.5 Helvetica, Verdana, sans-serif;
    color: white;
}

.info {
    vertical-align:top;
    font: bold 17px/1.5 Helvetica, Verdana, sans-serif;
    color: white;

a {
    color: inherit;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.img {
    float: left; 
    margin: 0 15px 0 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I want it to look like this:

1) Add wrapper for `<div>` containing text

2) Set `display: flex` property to `.channel` element

3) Center image by flex-properties

### Result

```css
body {
  margin: 20px;
  background: #595757;
}

.channel {
  display: flex;
  background: #393737;
}

.title {
  vertical-align: top;
  font: bold 20px/1.5 Helvetica, Verdana, sans-serif;
  color: white;
}

.info {
  vertical-align: top;
  font: bold 17px/1.5 Helvetica, Verdana, sans-serif;
  color: white;
}

a {
  color: inherit;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.img {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 0 15px 0 0;
}

.img img {
  height: 40px;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" onclick="Channel(SVT1HD)">
  <div class="channel">
    <div class="img">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/536/354" alt="SVT1">
    </div>
    <div>
      <div id="channel1_title" class="title">Aktuellt Program</div>
      <div id="channel1_info" class="info">Info</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</a>
```

[image]

Comment: I want the pic center infront of the two lines of text.

Comment: can you please show me how you centered the pic "3) Center image by flex-properties"

Comment: @HansPetterssonNyholm , Sorry. Updated codу-snippet. 1) `display: flex;` for `.channel`. 2) `display: flex; align-items: center;` for `.img`.  3) `height: 40px;` for `.img img`